# A promise problem to decide whether two given pure quantum states are close or far apart

Tags: quantum-computing, quantum-information

Consider this problem in quantum cryptography:

We have two pure states $\phi_1,\phi_2$ as input and constants $0 \leq \alpha <\beta \leq 1 $, where "Yes instances" are those for which $$\left|\left<\phi_1,\phi_2\right>\right| \leq \alpha$$ and "No instances" are those for which $$\left|\left<\phi_1,\phi_2\right>\right|\geq \beta$$

I need to devise a quantum circuit that accepts "Yes instances" with probability at least $p$, and "No instances" with at most probability $q$ for some $q<p$.

How can I do this? Is there a reference in which this problem is solved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Next time, please try to give an informative title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A standard tool is the swap test, which receives two unentangled pure states |*φ*<sub>1</sub>⟩ and |*φ*<sub>2</sub>⟩ and answers “equal” with probability (1+|⟨*φ*<sub>1</sub>|*φ*<sub>2</sub>⟩|<sup>2</sup>)/2 and “not equal” with probability (1−|⟨*φ*<sub>1</sub>|*φ*<sub>2</sub>⟩|<sup>2</sup>)/2.  See [BCWW01] (Figure 1 shows the circuit).

[BCWW01] Harry Buhrman, Richard Cleve, John Watrous, and Ronald de Wolf.  Quantum fingerprinting.  *Physical Review Letters*, 87, article 167902, Sept. 2001.  DOI: [10.1103/PhysRevLett.87.167902](http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.87.167902).  A preprint version: [arXiv:quant-ph/0102001](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0102001)v1.